# Angular2 components fail to communicate via observable in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make components send messages via a shared service, like in a [cookbook's](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#sts=Pass%20data%20from%20parent%20to%20child%20with%20input%20binding) "Parent and children communicate via a service" recipe. I have a `Sender` component that calls a service's method, in which an event is fired. And there's a `Receiver` component, which's just listens to events.

The problem is the `Receiver` doesn't get an event. Here's the code:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {Injectable, Component} from 'angular2/core';

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    private _subject = new Subject<any>();
    event$ = this._subject.asObservable();

    doFoo() {
        console.log('Doing foo hard...')
        this._subject.next('hey');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'receiver-component',
    template: 'Value is {{ value }}',
    providers: [
        TestService
    ],
})
export class ReceiverComponent {
    private value: number = 'nope';

    constructor(private service: TestService) {
        this.service.event$.subscribe(data => this.value = data)
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'sender-component',
    template: '<button (click)="fireEvent()">Click me</button>',
    providers: [
        TestService
    ],
})
export class SenderComponent {
    constructor (private service: TestService) {}

    fireEvent() {
        this.service.doFoo()
    }
}

bootstrap(SenderComponent);
bootstrap(ReceiverComponent);
```

When I click the button, I see the debug message from `TestService.doFoo()`, so it gets executed. But the event message just doesn't get passed. Why?

**Update**: I'm using `angular2@2.0.0-beta.7` and `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This it isn't a shared service. Each component gets it's own instance.

If you add the service to the `providers` list of the component, each component will get a new instance.

If you run `bootstrap()` twice, you create two distinct Angular applications which don't share anything. See the last lines of the code how to establish the connection anyway:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {Injectable, Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    private _subject = new Subject<any>();
    event$ = this._subject.asObservable();

    doFoo() {
        console.log('Doing foo hard...')
        this._subject.next('hey');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'receiver-component',
    template: 'Value is {{ value }}',
//    providers: [
//        TestService
//    ],
})
export class ReceiverComponent {
    private value: number = 'nope';

    constructor(private service: TestService) {
        this.service.event$.subscribe(data => this.value = data)
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'sender-component',
    template: '<button (click)="fireEvent()">Click me</button>',
//    providers: [
//        TestService
//    ],
})
export class SenderComponent {
    constructor (private service: TestService) {}

    fireEvent() {
        this.service.doFoo()
    }
}

sharedService = new TestService();
bootstrap(SenderComponent, [provide(TestService, {useValue: sharedService})]);
bootstrap(ReceiverComponent, [provide(TestService, {useValue: sharedService})]);
```

Comment: Günter, thanks a lot! You might want to import `provide` in your example to make it fully workable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - fixed.

Comment: i spend 4-5 to get this thing right and then i find this solution thanks a lot friends.