# trying to create an observable in a service, use it in a component and the subscribe it in another component angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I am trying to create an observable in a service.

then use it in one component and subscribe to it in another. has far as importing, and setting the providers array that is already done just looking to focus on the observer stuff

The service code:

```
selectedcityobs = Observable.create;
```

the component sending the info:

```
city;

this.venueservice.selectedcityobs obs =>{
obs.next(city);
}
```

the component receving the info.

```
 this.venueservice.selectedcityobs
   .subscribe(
    (city:any) 
     data =>{
     this.city = data;
     });
```

now most likely my syntax is way off and I am trying to fill in the holes. Im not looking for crazy syntax Im just looking for the right way to do this.

I saw this answer and it is confusing and not helping: [Angular2 components fail to communicate via observable in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766631/angular2-components-fail-to-communicate-via-observable-in-a-service)

im getting an error when I attempt to pass info to this observerable:

```
this.venueservice.selectedcityobs
        obs =>{
          obs.next(this.city);
        }
```

error: This inspection reports expression statements which are not assignments or calls. Such statements have no dubious semantics, are normally the result of programmer error.

Comment: You haven't actually identified what the issue is? Is it erroring at run time, compile time, data is incorrect.. ?

Comment: I have the syntax is wrong. I need the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'update' the observable with new data:

```
this.venueservice.selectedcityobs.next(city);
```

To subscribe to the observable:

```
this.venueservice.selectedcityobs
   .subscribe(data => this.city = data);
```

Comment: awesome, but the way in which i pass data to the observable is incorrect

Comment: i think i got it will be posting my solution

Comment: but in your answer you do not create an observable

Comment: @amazingCarrotSoup Im not sure what you want, you have the observable creation line: `selectedcityobs = Observable.create;` .. .?